# Выборка из двух таблиц SQL с условием

Tags: sql, запрос, выборка

[image: Карта Бд]

Задача: В какой город летит самолет с id = 3

Я написал от это... мне кажется так должно работать согласно синтаксису... но нет.

```
SELECT Pass_in_trip.place 
WHERE Trip.plane = '1132'
```

что я делаю не так, как написать правильно ?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что вы совсем ничего не поняли(

Comment: благодарю, у меня тоже есть такие подозрения. 
возможно учебный материал некачественный.
а еще мысли есть ?

Comment: Попробуйте почитать про SQL ну хоть что-нибудь! примеры там посмотреть...

Comment: Тут мне кажется проблема даже не в SQL, а в базовом английском

Comment: Харламов, что с вами не так? что за космическое западло... - ошибку заметили, а сказать прямо не решили. 

Я неправильно понял задание, пытаясь вытянуть не те поля, но там были и другие на которые я не обратил внимания....

Answer (score 0):

PLACE - переводится как место, и я выколупывал его, двойным запросом.
Но там были и другие поля на которые я не обратил внимания 'town_to'.

Когда заметил все решилось плоским запросом в одну таблицу.
Всем комментаторам дизлайк, за полное топорное отсутствие помощи и подсказок в чем проблема, даже при том что они вроде видели что я вытягиваю не то поле.

Решение вот

```
SELECT town_to FROM Trip WHERE id = '1123'
```

Comment: Совет, возле колонок БД есть кнопка с комментарием, справа от названия, можно понять, что за что отвечает. И кстати, Вы сами сказали, id должно быть 3, а в ответе и здесь берете что-то совсем другое, поэтому и вопросы остались о том, понимаете ли вы вообще что-то или нет.